# ASP.NET and Oracle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, webforms

I have found this web site really helpful since everybody helps here with the best answers. Now, i need a suggestion. I hope you would help me as before.

I need to develop an ASP.NET application with oracle database. Database server is physically separated from the application server. Now my question is which technology is preferable for this task? I mean ASP.NET MVC or General ASP or something... How do i use database technology?

I have studied ASP.NET MVC and found it difficult since it is in the primitive stage and i am not a professional programmer to make the best use of it. So please help me to proceed.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [Connecting to an Oracle Database Using ASP.NET—A Step-by-Step Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/database/article.php/c8477):

> There are numerous articles on .NET
>   and ASP.NET. However, recently I had
>   to develop an ASP.NET application
>   connecting to an Oracle database and,
>   to make everything work together, I
>   had to solve several problems. This
>   article will show you the step-by-step
>   process to develop an ASP.NET client
>   connecting to an Oracle database
>   server.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has released it's own implementation of an [ADO.NET Data Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html).

There are plenty of resources there, including some tutorials which should hopefully get you started.